# Using jQuery slideToggle to show a descirption in a hidden div element causes loop of mouse events or 'bouncing'

Tags: jquery, html

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JcBAd/839/  which demos the problem if you mover your mouse up from the bottom of the list you will see what I'm talking about.

I figure I need to be mores specific with, and not use $(this) or stop other events from firing while the animation is in splaying.

Comment: You might want to check out hoverIntent: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
$(".proj").hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".desc").slideToggle("fast");
},function(){
  $(this).children(".desc").hide();
});
```

Comment: and of course ! for a better and smoother effect, use jQuery Accordian as suggested below by Alytrem

Comment: Yep that fixes the issue for the moment :-) saves me until I change it to use the Accordian as @Alytrem suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQueryUI accordion for a better result. It's very lightweight (you can generate a jquery.ui.js containing only the necessary for accordion :-)).
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover

Answer (score 0):

I would put the headline into it's own `div` and use `$(this).next().slideToggle('fast')`. Maybe it's also a good idea not use `hover` but `click` so the `div` which contains text stays visible as long as you want. You can even have more than one text `div` visible at the same time.

I think part of the problem is that when you open a `div` below current one, the current `div` slides up and your mouse cursor isn't anymore hovering over the headline that you want to trigger the next event.